# Fill NAs with 0 until first numeric observation and last value until end of DF

Tags: r

I have a DF with account numbers and the balance on a monthly basis. For several months there is no value (NAs).
I want to fill in all NAs with 0 until R finds the first month with a value. When found the first observation it should fill in the last value found in the DF. For the end of the DF I want to use the last found observation. There is a sample of the DF, to make it easier to understand

```
Test = structure(list(Account = c("9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", 
                                  "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", 
                                  "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", 
                                  "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "9876", "1234", 
                                  "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
                                  "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
                                  "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
                                  "1234", "1234", "1234"), Date = structure(c(17409, 17439, 17470, 
                                                                              17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651, 17682, 17712, 17743, 
                                                                              17774, 17804, 17835, 17865, 17896, 17927, 17955, 17986, 18016, 
                                                                              18047, 18077, 18108, 18139, 18169, 18200, 18230, 17409, 17439, 
                                                                              17470, 17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651, 17682, 17712, 
                                                                              17743, 17774, 17804, 17835, 17865, 17896, 17927, 17955, 17986, 
                                                                              18016, 18047, 18077, 18108, 18139, 18169, 18200, 18230), class = "Date"), 
                      Balance = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, -0.0025, -0.0025, NA, 0, 0, 
                                  NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                  0, 0, NA, -2097.774, -2097.774, NA, NA, -3339.004, NA, NA, 
                                  NA, -5791.112, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, -90.30116, 
                                  -90.30116, NA, NA, NA, -474.4858), `First Observation` = c(NA, 
                                                                                             NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 
                                                                                             NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                             NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 
                                                                                             0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L)), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -56L))
```

Account number 9876:

So my desired output is that I get 0s in the balance for Date 2017-08 until 2017-10 for until the first observation on the 2017-11 is reached
2017-12 I would like to get the observation before (2017-11) with a balance of 0
2018-03, 2018-06, 2018-07 I would like to get the observation before (2018-02 and 2018-05) with a balance of -0.00250
From 2019-11 until the end of my time series I would like to get the last observation (here it is 2019-11, which is as well the end of my time series, but I cut the data. The original one reaches until 2022-08)

Account 1234:

For 2017-08 I would like to get 0 until I reach my first observation with a value
For 2017-11 and 12 I would like to get -2097.774 (which is the balance of 2017-10)

So basically I would like to have 0s for the beginning of my time series in the balance until I reach my first account balance, then take the last known balance for all other dates and then have the same value of my last balance until I reach the end of my time series.

Thank You!

Comment: Hello! It is nice that you provided a reproducible example, but it is not very minimal, which limits the possibility that someone will answer. An ideal setup would include a minimal size where your problem arises, with an expected output to make sure we know what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `fill` from the `tidyr` package allows you to fill missing values with the preceding or following entry.

After filling the values downwards, NAs before the first observation can then be replace with 0 using `replace_na`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Test %>%
  group_by(Account) %>%
  fill(Balance, .direction = 'down') %>%
  replace_na(list(Balance = 0))
```

Comment: But does the function give me 0s at the beginning of my time series, although the first known balance is not 0?

Comment: @MA_1760 If you fill with .direction = 'down', values before the first known will remain NA. Those can then be replaced with 0 using replace_na

Comment: oh yeah, tried it out and it works perfectly